# private files in drupal 6

Tags: 6, .htaccess, files

I have a sub directory in my files directory which I want to store private images. I display the images with their watermark, via the imagecache modules.

I thought I could make the directory (with the original images) hidden to the public simply by dropping an .htaccess file in the folder, with

```
deny from all
```

but the files are still publicly accessible. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to basically prevent hotlinking images, you can try the following in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```